# Somewhat lost with jquery + php + json

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I am starting to use the jquery $.ajax() but I can't get back what I want to...I send this:

```
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "graph_data.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: "casi=56&nada=48&nuevo=98&perfecto=100&vales=50&apenas=70&yeah=60",
    dataType: "json",
    error: function(xhr, desc, exceptionobj) {
      document.writeln("El error de XMLHTTPRequest dice: " + xhr.responseText);
    },
    success: function(json) {
      if (json.error) {
        alert(json.error);
        return;
      }
      var output = "";
      for (p in json) {
        output += p + " : " + json[p] + "\n";
      }
      document.writeln("Results: \n\n" + output);
    }
  });
});
```

and my php is:

```
<?php

$data = $_POST['data'];

function array2json($data){ 
    $json = $data;

    return json_encode($json);
}
?>
```

and when I execute this I come out with:

> Results:

just like that I used to have in the php a echo array2json statement but it just gave back gibberish...I really don't know what am I doing wrong and I've googled for about 3 hours just getting basically the same stuff. Also I don't know how to pass parameters to the "data:" in the $.ajax function in another way like getting info from the web page, can anyone please help me?

---

**Edit**

I did what you suggested and it prints the data now thank you very much =) however, I was wondering, how can I send the data to the "data:" part in jQuery so it takes it from let's say user input, also I was checking the php documentation and it says I'm allowed to write something like:

```
json_encode($a,JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_APOS|JSON_HEX_QUOT|JSON_HEX_AMP)
```

however, if I do that I get an error saying that json_encode accepts 1 parameter and I'm giving 2...any idea why? I'm using php 5.2

Comment: dataType: "json" - keep it lowercase.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First: the data you are passing to the PHP script will be in `$_POST`, not in `$_POST['data']`.

Next: you need to actually call the `array2json` function with some data... Is that the full code sample?

Also, I'm not sure what `array2json` is supposed to do... why not call `json_encode` directly?

For your example you can simply make your PHP file look like this:

```
print json_encode($_POST);
```

Finally, you should get a tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to easily debug your AJAX calls.

**EDIT**:

In order to send data from the user, all you have to do is have a [form](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) anywhere in your page, then catch the [submit](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/submit#fn) event of it and [serialize](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize) the  data, or simply [get the value](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val) of an individual input field. Then you can just construct your data query with it, as a string or an object. There is also the very popular [Form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) for jQuery that makes it all easier.

The reason you are getting an error is because the 2nd argument of [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/json_encode) was not added until PHP 5.3.0. So if you have anything earlier than that it's not available to you.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer! Thank you for answering the question and suggesting a way to perform the information transfer. THIS is FAQ / HOWTO material.